# How to make a sprite size change and fit to screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to change sprite x and y size for fit  the screen width and screen heigh. How can i use Screen.height and Screen.width functions on it ? I tried GUI.Label but it is not what i want.

(0,Screen.height/2 -Screen.height/4,Screen.width,Screen.Heigh/2) pozition and size value should have but when i use GUI.Label and change size the sprite size doesnt change. Sorry for my english. Thank you ...

This is what i tried:

```
GUI.Label ( new Rect (0,Screen.height/2 -Screen.height/4,Screen.width,Screen.Heigh/2) ,  image);
```

Comment: Java is very different from JavaScript, which in turn is not the same as UnityScript that Unity likens to call JavaScript. Tags updated.

Comment: oh thank you so javascript is for website development ? or something like that ?

Comment: + java and javascript isn't the same ?

Comment: No. Java is static, js is dynamic language

Comment: not by a long shot! http://stackoverflow.com/a/5184356/201863  <= there are also helpful answers in that thread so look around ;)

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Unity's new UI (4.6) is wonderful and can easily be changed by using the scale settings under the Canvas object.

Comment: i use the last version 4.6.x

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you might want to check out the new UI system in 4.6.x

However, if you want to use GUI functions then maybe look into [GUI.DrawTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.DrawTexture.html) as it will let you scale your texture to the size you want in a number of ways depending on the scale mode you choose.

For your sprite to fill the screen however, you will want to use the Rect:

```
new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height); //left, top, width, height
```